# Should I upvote an interesting, thoughtful, off-topic question?

Tags: discussion, voting

[This question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/62039/167) by a brand-new user is interesting, decently well written, and totally off topic.  I'm torn: I want to upvote it because in isolation it's a good *question*, but I don't want to encourage off-topic asking.

**Should I upvote interesting, thoughtful, but off-topic questions?**

*In the absence of an Aviation-specific policy, links to Meta.SE best practices are fine, as I'm sure this question has been beaten to death on other sites in the network.*

Comment: Related on MSE: [Should an off-topic question always be downvoted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199127)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you be torn if it was not a new user?

**If** the answer is also yes, then yes upvote it.

> As long as the votes target the post, not the user, all votes are legitimate. ([Are sympathy/enthusiasm upvotes legitimate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/221783))

Some may disagree why it has been upvoted, but hey, that *is* voting. And to quote the help center:

> [Vote up](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) a question, answer or comment that **you feel** is especially useful.
>
> [Vote down](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down) an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.

What would be more helpful IMO for the asker (and for anyone looking for an answer to the same question), is to guide the asker in a comment on where to go (e.g., a relevant network site).